# Cat5E wall plate wiring: Used the diagram that came with the wall plate. It doesn't work. Any suggestions? Turns the switch port light off

Tags: installation, wired-networking, cat5e

I ran a CAT5E cable from a functioning switch port and cut one end off and installed a wall plate, using the wiring color code per the chart with the wall plate.  When connecting to a computer via a patch cable to the wall plate, 
the switch port light goes out.  The switch port was tested by using a patch cable directly to a computer and it works fine. The wall plate is the type with screw down connections on the back.  Any suggestions as to why this doesn't work?

Comment: Screw down jacks tend to be four-conductor or six-conductor, not eight-conductor. Also, what's the make of the wall plate, and does the manufacturer certify it as CAT 5E compliant? Please click [edit] and advise.

Comment: It is an 8 wire Cat5E jack per the manufacturer.

Comment: "per the manufacturer." which manufacturer?

Comment: did the diagram on the panel indicate a straight-though wiring scheme (orange to orange, blue to blue, etc)? if the plates ancient it may think you have a hub and suggested a cross-patch scheme.

Comment: Could you describe what it said to wire up (ie 1 - Green Stripe, 2 Green , 3 Orange Stiped, 6 4 Blue , 5 Blue Stripe, 6 Orange, 7 Brown, strip 8 Brown

Comment: Even without crossover [or errors] there are two ways to wire ethernet. If they gave you 2 diagrams, it's almost always the 2nd diagram you need, not the first. [This is presumably for the same reasons that USB cables only fit the ***third*** way round, to catch out the unwary ;)